# Can the constant $3$ in the Vitali covering lemma be replaced by any positive constant less than that in the finite case?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, real-numbers

I am stuck with a question that the constant $3$ in the [Vitali covering lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma) can not be replaced by any positive constant less than that in the finite case.

Observe that this question is different from the question of why $3$ is considered as bad constant because I am not considering infinite case here.

For example, I was thinking in real line and the argument can be generalised in the higher dimension; if I have $(0,4)$ and constant is $c<3$ then taking the interval $(8,4+\frac{3-c}{2})$ or anything would not give me my answer. So I was doubting the validity of the statement in a metric space but I don't know whether I am missing anything or not!!

Answer (score 2):

You idea is good. Even more simple: a collection consisting of two closed touching balls of equal radius shows that $3$ cannot be replaced by a smaller number.